# Custom python application name in db2 list application output

Tags: python, database, db2, odbc, db2-luw

Connect to db2 with python ibm_db_dbi and get the list of applicationsn `NAME` column always shows **python**.

```
import ibm_db_dbi
db2ConnArgs = "DATABASE=%s;HOSTNAME=%s;PORT=%s;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=%s;PWD=%s;" % ('SAMPLE', 'localhost', 50000, 'db2test', 'db2test')
db2ConnDict = {ibm_db_dbi.SQL_ATTR_CURRENT_SCHEMA:'SAMPLE'}
dbhandle = ibm_db_dbi.connect(db2ConnArgs,"", "","","",db2ConnDict)
```

Run `db2 list application`

```
Auth Id  Application    Appl.      Application Id                                                 DB       # of
        Name           Handle                                                                    Name    Agents
-------- -------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
DB2TEST  python         47         127.0.0.1.34218.180529224354                                   SAMPLE   1
```

Is it possible to assign a custom name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using `ibm_db_dbi.ibm_db.SQL_ATTR_INFO_PROGRAMNAME` connection attribute

```
import ibm_db_dbi
db2ConnArgs = "DATABASE=%s;HOSTNAME=%s;PORT=%s;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=%s;PWD=%s;" % ('SAMPLE', 'localhost', 50000, 'db2test', 'db2test')
db2ConnDict = {ibm_db_dbi.SQL_ATTR_CURRENT_SCHEMA:'SAMPLE', ibm_db_dbi.ibm_db.SQL_ATTR_INFO_PROGRAMNAME : 'luis_app'}
dbhandle = ibm_db_dbi.connect(db2ConnArgs,"", "","","",db2ConnDict)
```

Run `db2 list application`

```
Auth Id  Application    Appl.      Application Id                                                 DB       # of
        Name           Handle                                                                    Name    Agents
-------- -------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
DB2TEST  luis_app       31         127.0.0.1.34194.180529223939                                   SAMPLE   1
```

Original bug report:
https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/144